# Mapping an array of tuples results in a strange error about types

Tags: swift

My method for finding the maximum y value in an array of tuples is resulting in a error that I can't understand.

```
let a: [(x: Float, y: Float)]? = [(x:5,y:9),(x:1,y:4),(x:4,y:3),(x:2,y:5),(x:6,y:8)]
let maxY = a.map { $0.y }.max()
```

It throws an error like:

[image: error]

Comment: Go right ahead. What's stopping you? Did you try reading the docs on the `max` method? It's sitting right there, waiting like an operator to take your call. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2294243-max

Comment: That's not an array of `struct`. That's an array of tuples.

Comment: i tried this. let maxY = a.map { $0.y }.max()
 but no luck.

Comment: It's not about luck. It's about thinking. And I didn't say `map`, I said `max`.

Comment: @Zord: That actually  looks quite right ...

Comment: it works so cool, with arrays like [a(1), a(2), a(3)] or some array like [1,2,3] with max functions. but some structs or tuples whatever , it is not working with my logics

Comment: @Zord It works for me in a playground.

Comment: I have added an image to my question, Click this "It throws an error like this"

Comment: @Zord According to your error, your `data` variable must be an array of arrays

Comment: no its an array of tuple, here is the data declaration: var data: [(x: Float, y: Float)]?

Comment: @Zord: `let a = [(x:5,y:9),(x:1,y:4),(x:4,y:3),(x:2,y:5),(x:6,y:8)] ; let maxY = a.map { $0.y }.max()` compiles without problems. Did you show your real code?

Comment: @Zord The error is a red herring. When you call map on an optional type, the parameter is going to be of the type the optional might contain. You need to do `a?.map` to conditionally call `map` and unwrap the contained value. This will result in the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: wooooo.... @AllenHumphreys you made me realize how dumb I was. That fixed the problem. Actually these error codes make no proper sense, so I was worried. `Its really bad to see something like "?" should be followed even after assigning values to those objects satisfying optional rules

Comment: @Zord You should've worded your question so that it was about the error, not what your code was trying to do. As it is written, it seems like you're asking people to do your work for you, when in reality you already had the answer, but were instead stuck on an error that you weren't able to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
let maxY = a.map({ $0.y }).max()
```

Here you used `map` to create another array that contains only `y`s, and then used `max()` to find the max value of these `y`s.

You can also do it this way:

```
let maxY = a.max { $0.y < $1.y }?.y
```

Here you used `max` passing a closure to it, this closure compares the `y` property of the values of the array, and then you take the `y` of the tuple that contains the max y.

As pointed out by @Allen Humphreys in the comments, you can also do it using `reduce` this way:

```
let maxY = a.reduce(Int.min) { max($0, $1.y) }
```

Here you reduces the array into one value only, which will be max y.

Comment: You could also do it with reduce, just for fun `a.reduce(Int.min) { max($0, $1.y) }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alen @matt and @Abdul for code snippet.

I made a mistake by calling max functions on an optional object.

The original code was,

```
var data: [(x: Float, y: Float)]?
data = [(x:5,y:9),(x:1,y:4),(x:4,y:3),(x:2,y:5),(x:6,y:8)]
let maxY = data.map({ $0.y }).max()
```

And I realized that I didnt notice "?" this thingy hooking compilation error when executed the code I have written.

well, it supposed to be ,

```
   let maxY = data?.map({ $0.y }).max()
```

Comment: why don't you just declare data non optional `var data: [(x: Float, y: Float)] = []`

Comment: yea but this is a test run.. it supposed to be dynamic values in future